# Do compilers usually have special optimizations for strings?

Tags: c++, string, compiler-optimization, stdstring

Often times you see things like

```
std::map<std::string, somethingelse> m_named_objects;
```

or

```
std::string state;

//...

if(state == "EXIT")
   exit();
else if(state == "california")
   hot();
```

where people use strings purely to make something more readable. The same thing could easily be achieved with something like integer-IDs.

Can modern compilers (msvc, g++, etc.) usually employ special optimizations for these types of cases? Or should this be avoided because of bad performance or for other reasons?

Comment: I'm not sure there are any such optimizations that are valid in the presence of separate compilation.

Comment: I usually see enums instead of these maps when people want to enhance readability. enum STATE {EXIT, CALIFORNIA, (etc)}; Then you can have "if (state == EXIT)" etc.

Comment: How long do you think it takes to compare the four bytes of "EXIT"?

Comment: @Vanessa: That's fine for in-code readability. But what if you're debugging and you want to know what the current `state` is? It's not very obvious from the number; you'd have to look it up in the enum (assuming that your debugger/IDE can't look it up for you). Whereas with a string, every debugger can show you the value.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Then get a better debugger. At least for Visual Studio, the debugger does show the name of enumerator associated with the integer value.

Comment: @In silico: That's assuming it's store in an enumeration type. If it happens to be stored in a simple integer, you get nothing.

Comment: @Nicol: If you store your string in an array of integers you don't get anything either... but then that's plain stupid. Don't subvert the type system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can modern compilers (msvc, g++, etc.) usually employ special optimizations for these types of cases?

As far as I know, compilers don't make those kinds of optimizations. It's definitely not a "standard" optimization.

> ...where people use strings purely to make something more readable.

At least for your second case, it seems to me that enumerations are more readable and can be faster (since integer comparisons are rather cheap relative to string comparison).

```
enum State
{
    Alabama,
    Alaska,
    Arizona,
    Arkansas, 
    California,
    Colorado,
    Connecticut,
    Delaware,
    // ... More
};

// ...

State state = California;
if(state == California) { /* true */ }
```

Comment: That is correct, use enumeration instead of string. If you really have to use strings though, don't bug yourself with the performance so much, checking a couple characters is not THAT bad!

Comment: If performance is put aside, the most apparent advantage of using enums instead of strings is that enums can be used in a switch statement whereas strings cannot.

Comment: The most apparent advantage is that the compiler will tell you if you write `california` instead of `California`.

Answer (score 1):

Libraries do.

Compilers might optimize by aliasing shared/identical static strings (assuming that they really are treated as constants).

All C++ standard library implementation I'm currently aware of, sport a 'small string optimization', meaning that no extra heap allocation needs to occur for small strings; I.e.

```
std::string a("small");
```

will be fully auto (stack) allocated - in highly optimized cases perhaps even register allocated(?)

---

If you need blazingly fast string lookups and can afford some time spent building your datastructure, look at Tries (WP: [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), [Radix_tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree))

**As far as drop-in replacements go**  usually a lot can be gained by using a *properly tuned* hash map instead of a RB-tree based one:

```
std::map<std::string, somethingelse> m_named_objects;
```

replace by

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, somethingelse> m_named_objects;
```

Be happy

Comment: added constructive ideas for the `map` key optimization case

Answer (score 0):

In the examples given the compiler generally cannot optimize because the content is runtime dependent.

`std::map<std::string, int>` does not have the most desirable performance characteristics as `operator<()` on a `std::string` is relatively expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Optimizations for strings are for libraries, not compilers. If you want string-like identifiers, enums are one possibility. But a better one, particularly for printing and debugging, is a fixed-length identifier string class.

It would be convertible to `const char *` and `std::string`, but it would have zero memory allocations. Instead, it would just be a wrapper around a 32-character (or whatever you want) array.

The best part is that, since it's an identifier, you don't care about ASCII character-by-character comparisons. `operator<` can just read the 32-character array as 8 `uint32_t`s, or even as 4 `uint64_t`s. All you need is *an* ordering, not a specific ordering. `operator==` can do similar tests.

It's a pretty simple class to write. If you want case-insensitive comparisons, you could just convert the string to lowercase when you copy it into the object.

If you need strings longer than 31 bytes (one for the `\0` terminator), then I would suggest truncating the string down to size. But truncate from the *middle* of the given string, not the end. The beginnings and end of identifiers tend to be more unique than the middle. You could even put some special characters in a truncated string to identify that it is a truncated version.

It is also possible to take this idea and put a hash in the string. So the first 4 bytes would be a hash of the *original* string, not of the truncation. Comparison tests would just use the hash, and the other 28 bytes are there to make it human-readable.